# Learn Prolog Now! DCG Practice Example

Tags: prolog, grammar, dcg

I have been progressing through [Learn Prolog Now!](http://learnprolognow.org) as self-study and am now learning about Definite Clause Grammars. I am having some difficulty with one of the Practical Session's tasks. [The task](http://cs.union.edu/~striegnk/learn-prolog-now/html/node63.html) reads:

> The formal language a<sup>n</sup>b<sup>2m</sup>c<sup>2m</sup>d<sup>n</sup> consists of all strings of the following form: an unbroken block of *a*s followed by an unbroken block of *b*s followed by an unbroken block of *c*s followed by an unbroken block of *d*s, such that the *a* and *d* blocks are exactly the same length, and the *c* and *d* blocks are also exactly the same length and furthermore consist of an even number of *c*s and *d*s respectively. For example, *ε*, *abbccd*, and *aaabbbbccccddd* all belong to a<sup>n</sup>b<sup>2m</sup>c<sup>2m</sup>d<sup>n</sup>. Write a DCG that generates this language.

I am able to write rules that generate a<sup>n</sup>d<sup>n</sup>, b<sup>2m</sup>c<sup>2m</sup>, and even a<sup>n</sup>b<sup>2m</sup> and c<sup>2m</sup>d<sup>n</sup>... but I can't seem to join all these rules into a<sup>n</sup>b<sup>2m</sup>c<sup>2m</sup>d<sup>n</sup>.  The following are my rules that can generate a<sup>n</sup>d<sup>n</sup> and b<sup>2m</sup>c<sup>2m</sup>.

```
s1 --> [].
s1 --> a,s1,d.
a --> [a].
d --> [d].

s2 --> [].
s2 --> c,c,s2,d,d.
c --> [c].
d --> [d].
```

Is a<sup>n</sup>b<sup>2m</sup>c<sup>2m</sup>d<sup>n</sup> really a CFG, and is it possible to write a DCG using only what was taught in the lesson (no additional arguments or code, etc)? If so, can anyone offer me some guidance how I can join these so that I can solve the given task?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

@Timothy, your answer works, but it generates duplicates:

```
?- length(S,_), s(S,[]).
S = [] ;
S = [a, d] ;
S = [a, d] ;            % XXX
S = [b, b, c, c] ;
S = [a, a, d, d] ;
S = [a, a, d, d] ;      % XXX
```

This can be fixed by removing one clause, leaving the DCG:

```
s --> x.
s --> a,s,d.

x --> [].
x --> b,b,x,c,c.

% a, b, c, d the same
```

This generates:

```
?- length(S,_), s(S,[]).
S = [] ;
S = [a, d] ;
S = [b, b, c, c] ;
S = [a, a, d, d] ;
S = [a, b, b, c, c, d] ;
S = [a, a, a, d, d, d] ;
S = [b, b, b, b, c, c, c, c] ;
S = [a, a, b, b, c, c, d, d] ;
S = [a, a, a, a, d, d, d, d] ;
```

Answer (score 3):

I believe I figured it out...

```
s --> x.
s --> a,d.
s --> a,s,d.

x --> [].
x --> b,b,x,c,c.

a --> [a].
b --> [b].
c --> [c].
d --> [d].

?- s([],[]).
Yes

?- s([a,b,c,c,d],[]).
No

?- s([a,a,a,b,b,c,c,d,d,d],[]).
Yes
```

It's amusing to look at the solution and think, "I racked my brain over *that*?" But I guess that's half the fun of learning something new, especially when it's something like logic programing coming from an imperative programming background.

Comment: It's hard, but is pays off. Logic programming (and lazy FP) knowledge esp. served me when learning the iterator concept in C++, Java and Python.

Answer (score 0):

How about something like:

```
n(L,N) --> n(L,N,0).

n(_,N,N) --> [], !.
n(L,N,K) --> L, {K1 is K + 1}, n(L, N, K1).

abbccd(N,M) -->
    {M1 is 2*M},
    n("a",N),
    n("b",M1),
    n("c",M1),
    n("d",N).

gen :-
    forall((
           between(1,4,N),
        between(1,4,M),
        phrase(abbccd(N,M),S),
        string_to_atom(S,A)
           ),
           writeln(A)).
```

executing:

```
 ?- gen.
abbccd
abbbbccccd
abbbbbbccccccd
abbbbbbbbccccccccd
aabbccdd
aabbbbccccdd
aabbbbbbccccccdd
aabbbbbbbbccccccccdd
aaabbccddd
aaabbbbccccddd
aaabbbbbbccccccddd
aaabbbbbbbbccccccccddd
aaaabbccdddd
aaaabbbbccccdddd
aaaabbbbbbccccccdddd
aaaabbbbbbbbccccccccdddd
true.
```

Comment: Thank you, Xonix. That works, but unfortunately it uses concepts not covered until later (code blocks, cuts, etc). I honestly think it's not possible using only simple rules... or if it is, it's not worth the effort because in the "real world" one would take advantage of the other concepts like you did in your sample.